# Using STArray and ignore the return of modify in Purescript

Tags: purescript

I think I'm close to what I want, though I suspect I'm not understanding how `thaw` / `TH Region` works.

Here is what I'm trying to implement (at least roughly)

```hs
modifyPerIndex :: forall t a. Foldable t => t (Tuple Int (a -> a)) -> Array a -> Array a
modifyPerIndex foldableActions array = run do
  mutableArray <- thaw array
  let actions = fromFoldable foldableActions
  foreach actions (\(Tuple index action) -> modify index action mutableArray)
  freeze mutableArray
```

This is sort of how I imagine `updateAtIndices` works. I suppose I could write `modifyPerIndex` to use `updateAtIndices` by reading in the values, applying the `(a -> a)` and mapping the result into a list of Tuples to be sent to updateAtIndices.

I'm curious how to do it this way though.

In the code above `modify` returns `ST h Boolean`, which I'd like to change into `ST h Unit`. That's where I'm lost. I get that `h` here is a constraint put on mutable data to stop it from leaving `run`, what I don't understand is how to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options. But it has nothing to do with `h`. You don't have to "use" it for anything, and you don't have to worry about it at all.

First, the most dumb and straightforward approach - just bind the result to an ignored variable and then separately return `unit`:

```hs
foreach actions \(Tuple index action) -> do
  _ <- modify index action mutableArray
  pure unit
```

Alternatively, you can use [`void`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/5.0.0/docs/Data.Functor#v:void), which does more or less the same thing under the hood:

```hs
foreach actions \(Tuple index action) -> void $ modify index action mutableArray
```

But I would go straight for [`for_`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foldable-traversable/5.0.0/docs/Data.Foldable#v:for_), which is the same as `foreach`, but works for any monad (not just `ST`) and ignores individual iterations' return values:

```hs
for_ actions \(Tuple index action) -> modify index action mutableArray
```

Comment: Hey, followup question. I'm getting an error that I can't figure out. `Could not match type Array with type STArray h0` when I'm binding mutableArray.

Comment: Not enough information for an answer. When getting type mismatch errors, try adding type signatures to things, e.g. `mutableArray :: STArray h a <- ...`. This will pin one end of the mismatch and force the compiler to show you the other end.

Comment: I'm not sure how to say what type `h` is in order to pin one end of the mismatch

Comment: You can use a partial signature `:: STArray _ a`